# How can I close a Chrome page?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, c#-4.0, sendkeys

I want to close Chrome pages with this code.

```
  textPrint("^W");//Have to close 1 page from chrome

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  private void textPrint(String text)
  {
    SendKeys.SendWait(text);
  }
```

But when I use this code, Chrome closes all pages. How can I solve this problem, I want to close only the page that is opened?

EDIT:
I tried Control + w. It is working. W doesnt work need to make lovercase

Comment: are you closing the last tab in Chrome? If you close last tab, browser will close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should send "^w".  Ctrl+Shift+W closes all tabs

Comment: I found why it is because of my uppercase W :):)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried control+f4?

```
textPrint("^{f4}");
```